# Upgraded PHP version to 5.4.1, MAMP URLs broken, so downgraded but still broken?

Tags: php, macos, apache, mamp

OK, so (retrospectively, quite stupidly), I upgraded my mac osx PHP version (not mamp php) from 5.3.28 to 5.4.10, to try and install composer. Now my MAMP sites don't seem to be loading. (I am not a backender.)

**1. I upgraded mamp**

At the end of the upgrade the final messages in terminal were as follows:

```
Create symlink /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
Restarting Apache
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.2 for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

But when I checked the php version in terminal, it still said 5.3.28.

**2. MAMP start page loaded, sites didn't work**

Suddenly none of my MAMP sites were working. I have set the virtual hosts in httpd-vhosts.conf (and using sudo vim /etc/hosts). These have been working for like 3 years with no problem.

MAMP still loads the start page, but when I load a site I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) PHP/5.4.41 DAV/2 Server at domain.dev Port 80
```

**3. Reinstalled MAMP**

So I then uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP, and restored all my settings, which again still loads up fine (the MAMP php version is now 5.6.7).

**4. Tried downgrading mac php back to 5.3.28**

I then tried to downgrade back to PHP 5.3.28, but that wouldn't work when I tried to use:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.3.28
```

So I just used:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.3
```

And it appears to have downgraded to **5.3.29**, but with the following **error** at the end:

```
Executing post-install script /tmp/5.3-frontenddev-post-install
Restarting Apache
httpd: Syntax error on line 665 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _libiconv\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/lib/libintl.8.dylib\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib\n in /usr/local/php5/lib/libintl.8.dylib
```

When I check the php version, it still says '5.3.28' :(

**5. Someone save me**

The exact same problem persists. I have no idea what's gone wrong or how to fix it. Any help would be super appreciated!

*Running Mac Lion 10.7.5*

Comment: OK, so just realised that when I disable MAMP, I get exactly the same error. So whether it's running or not makes no difference. Same issue occurs. I can access the sites using 'localhost/domain.dev' but not with just the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So MAMP then stopped working completely. But against all odds, I managed to fix it.

---

I followed this guide and reinstalled PHP 5.3:

http://benedmunds.com/php/2014/10/16/fixing-homebrew-php-apache-after-yosemite/

I got an error when I got to this line:

```
$ brew reinstall php53 --with-mysql --with-pgsql --with-apache
```

---

So I followed the beginning of this guide: 
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mac/osx-brew-php-mysql-nginx/

Until I got to the install line tried it again to install 5.3:

```
brew search php

brew tap josegonzalez/php

brew tap homebrew/dupes

brew options php53

brew reinstall php53 --with-mysql --with-pgsql --with-apache
```

Took a little while, finished up. Restarted MAMP, and everything works again.

Phew.

**Update**

Had issues loading the MAMP start page too afterwards. Solved them by stopping OSX apache from running. It must have been taking over or something...

```
sudo apachectl stop
```